# What is the way in MVC to hold action parameter values on the client side and use them while redirecting to a an action with parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If I am on a page and decide to click cancel,  I want to redirect it to an action method with parameters. But to do that, what is the way to hold the action parameter values on the page and use them later on a click of link or button.

One way is to create hidden fields in the page while page is rendered and hold the values in them. Extract the value from them using Java script and alter the documen

Is this the right way to do it in mvc or there is a cleaner way to accomplish this. Please suggest.

Comment: If you need to redirect user to an action with parameters by link you can use `@Html.ActionLink()` method overload which takes `object` to render route parameters - `@Html.ActionLink("Link text","Action","Controller", new { parameter=value }, null)`. Also one good tip - be careful with correct method overload since `@Html.ActionLink("Link text","Action","Controller", new { parameter=value })` will not works because `new { parameter=value }`  will be html attribute not route value in rendered link.

Comment: In case I need to use a button... where can i hold the parameter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need to use a button you will need to use jquery (or vanilla java script) to redirect user somewhere by button. As an option you can create button with, for example, `data-url` attribute and use `@Url.Action` helper method (instead of `Html.ActionLink`. `ActionLink` generates entire `a` tag with all html parameters like `href` and other which you provide, but `Url.Action` generates only url - the value of href attribute) to generate link with parameters and implement button click event handler to redirect user by this url. Example:

**Button (view, Razor syntax):**

```
<input type="button" data-url="@Url.Action("Action","Controller", new { parameter=value }, null)" value="Click me" id="my-button"/>
```

**Related jquery:**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#my-button').click(function(){
            window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1) if you already have the parameters in database.

All you need to is pass a `id` or something of the clicked data from which you can retrieve the required values in the controller.

In your syntax pass the values.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("cancle","ActionName","ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id, type = "button" })
```

use this `id` in the controller and get the parameters from database and proceed.

2)if parameters are obtained dynamically (not available in DB).

your approach will be good (by saving it in hidden fields and later retrieving in controller or processing it in JS).